# How To Disable Return In Input But Allow Enter Event Key To Be Used To Send Message

Tags: jquery

I added a code to my chat system, which allows the enter key to send the message, instead of the user pressing the send button manually.

But, in the input chat box, once the enter button is pressed, the chat box still reads it as a "return" which puts an unnecessary empty bottom line before sending.

**see example**
[image: see example]

How can I disable the input from reading it as "return" but still allow the enter event key to allow the sending of the message?

Here's the code I have

```
<script>
    jQuery('document').ready(function($) {

        $('body').on('click', '.um-bottom-header', function() {
            $('.um-bottom-body').toggleClass('close');
            $('.um-bottom-header .icons').toggleClass('open');
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.um-personal-chat-icons .far', function() {
            $(this).parents('.um-message-modal').toggleClass('close')
            // $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.um-message-modal.close', function() {
            $(this).removeClass('close');
        });
        // function submitName(e) {
        //   if (e.code === 'Enter') {
        //     document.getElementById('send-btn').click();
        //   }
        // }
        $('body').on('keyup', '#um_message_text', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                $(".um-message-send").click();
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

It's the code towards the bottom, I just wanted to include the script section.

Comment: Try adding `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Where would I add this?

Comment: Into the function `submitName`

Comment: So replace event.preventDefault(); with 'e.preventDefault();?

Comment: No, sorry i see the commented function

Comment: Maybe do it in `keydown` instead of `keyup`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

change your last event to:

```
$('body').on('keypress', '#um_message_text', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".um-message-send").click();
        }
    });
```